# Access json data using jquery (returned by php)

Tags: post, json

Q1.here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
 Runners
</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="printrunners"> Print Runners</button>
 <div id="printrunnershere"></div>
<script src="printrunners1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript is here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("#printrunners").click(function()
         {


 $.getJSON("printrunners.php?action=getrunners", 

function(json)  //also tried without "?action=getrunner" line
               {
               $.each(json.runners,function()
                  {
                   var info= 'Name:  '+this['fname']+' '+ this['lname']+'   Gender: '+this['gender']+'     Finish Time: '+this['finish_time'];
                   $("#printrunnershere").append(info);
                  });

           });
       });
```

});

printrunners.php here:

```
<?php
if($_GET)  //also tried without it with respect to "?action=getrunner"
 {
   if($_GET['action']=="getrunners") // also tried without it w.r.t "?action=getrunner"
     {
        mysql_connect("localhost","runner_db_user","runner_db_user_password");
        mysql_select_db("runner_info");
        $result=mysql_query("select  * from runner");
        $runners=array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {
            array_push($runners, array('fname' => $row['fname'], 'lname' => $row['lname'], 'gender' => $row['gender'], 'finish_time' => $row['finish_time']));
         }
      echo json_encode(array("runners" =>$runners));
     }
 }

?>
```

Q2. also I used post() to insert a row in same above database it inserts but can't access json data returned by php program:

javascript here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('#add').click(function()
    {

      var data=$("#form1 :input").serializeArray();

      $.post($("#form1").attr('action'),data,function(json){

            if(json.status=='success')
             {

               alert (json.message);
             }
             if(json.status=='fail')
              {
                alert(json.message);
               }
        },"json");
     });


    $("#form1").submit(function()
       {
          return false;
       });

   });
```

it's php here:

```
<?php


   $fname=htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
   $lname=htmlspecialchars($_POST["lname"]);
   $gender=htmlspecialchars($_POST["gender"]);
   $finish_time=htmlspecialchars($_POST["finish_time"]);



  $query="insert into runners (fname,lname,gender,finish_time) values('$fname','$lname','$gender','$finish_time')" ;

  $result=db_connection($query);

if($result)
   {
    $msg="Runner  " .fname."".lname."added successfully";
success($msg);
   }
  else
   {

     fail("insert failed");
   }
exit;




function fail($message) 
  {
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
  } 
function success($message)
  { 
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
  }

function db_connection($query1)
 {
  mysql_connect("localhost","runner_db_user","runner_db_password")
    OR die(fail('Could not connect to database.'));

   mysql_select_db("runner_info");

   return  mysql_query($query1);

 }

?>
```

ITS FRONT END(html page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
 add runner
</title>
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsonuse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <form id="addrunnerform" name="addrunnerform" method="post" action="addrunner.php">
   First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="name"></br>
   Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></br>
   Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="m" checked>Male
           <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="f">Female</br>
   Finish Time: <input type="text" id="finish_time" name="finish_time"></br>
 <button type="submit" id="add" name="add">ADD</button>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: @kielni : In Q2 jquery program nothing happens the form remains as it is and is not displaying any alert message as it should according to php json response. however row is inserted in database with values i put in form fields and I again have tested the php program separately also, by giving values to it's variables manually & is displaying result- {"status":"success","message":"Runner  Smart Kielni added successfully"}

Comment: so please help me .at the time when i raised this question was 10:00 pm so please don't bother if i responded so late because i went to sleep and after 12hours i responded your comment and waited whole day. now i deleted my old comment and typed new. currently the time is same again, so... i will visit this question at least after 12 hours.  thanx  but please respond.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of what you're trying to do.  Try running it in Firebug and see if you can trace what's happening.

Comment: For Question no.2 I tried to look in to firebug's tabs(dom,html,css) but don't know what to look for. so please tell me how should I use Firebug to track problem. Also when I place an alert message within callback function of post() method  no alert is shown(on running the program) means callback function is not called, is my post() function is wrong.

Comment: now I have posted my whole program code for Question2(first solve this) so please try to run it by yourself and tell me what the problem is and its solution please(or tell me how to find the problem & its solution). I'm waiting........